# apex pass parameter null

Tags: apex, parameters, null

I'm trying to pass a pasrameter to mi apex class to search a contact but when i debug that parameter in the apex class, always return "null" and i dont know why... someone knows why? Thanks!

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="contactEditApex">
        <aura:attribute name="newContact" type="contact__c"
         default="{ 'sobjectType': 'contact__c',
                        'Name': '',
                        'first_name__c': '',
                        'last_name__c': '',
                        'document_number__c': 0,
                        'height__c': 0,
                        'gender__c': '',
                        'eyes_color__c': '',
                        'hair_color__c': '', }"/>
    <aura:attribute name="message" type="String" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="isButtonActive" type="Boolean" default="false" />
    <aura:attribute name="documentNumber" type="Integer" default="100" />
    <div>
        <lightning:input
        name="inline-search-input"
        label="Search the document number"
        type="search"
        aura:id="search"/>
        <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Search" title="Brand action" onclick="{! c.handleClick }" />
    </div>
    <form class="slds-form_stacked">
        <lightning:input aura:id="field" label="First name" name="firstname" disabled="{!v.isButtonActive}" value="{!v.newContact.first_name__c}"/>
        <lightning:input aura:id="field" label="Last name" name="lastname" value="{!v.newContact.last_name__c}" />
        <lightning:input aura:id="field" type="number" label="Document number" name="Document" value="{!v.newContact.document_number__c}"/>
        <lightning:input aura:id="field" type="number" name="height" label="height" value="{!v.newContact.height__c}" />
        <lightning:select aura:id="field" label="Select your gender" name="gender" value="{!v.newContact.gender__c}">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="male">Male</option>
                <option value="female">Female</option>
                <option value="undefined">Undefined</option>
        </lightning:select>
        <lightning:input aura:id="field" label="Eyes color" name="eyescolor" value="{!v.newContact.eyes_color__c}" />
        <lightning:input aura:id="field" label="Hair color" name="haircolor" value="{!v.newContact.hair_color__c}" />
        <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Save" title="Brand action" onclick="{! c.saveContact }" />
        <p>{!v.message}</p>
    </form>
    
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    saveContact : function(component, event, helper) {
        var saveContactAction = component.get("c.createContact");
        saveContactAction.setParams({
                "contact": component.get("v.newContact")
            });
        saveContactAction.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.message", "Contact created successfully");
            }
            else if (state === "ERROR") {
                console.log('Problem saving contact, response state: ' + state);
            }
            else {
                console.log('Unknown problem, response state: ' + state);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(saveContactAction);
    },
    handleClick : function(component, event, helper) {
        let searchValue = component.find("search").get("v.value")
        // cambio el value a un numero porque lo trae en forma de string
        var valueToNumber = parseInt(searchValue)
    
        let action = component.get("c.getcontact");
        // no puedo pasarle un parametro sin que devuelva null desde la apex class
        // del lado de apex deje un unico dni para que traija y resuelva la funcionalidad pero que solo le falta pasarle bien el parametro
        action.setParams({"valueToNumber": valueToNumber});


        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            let state = response.getState();
            let respuesta = response.getReturnValue()[0]
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                 component.set("v.newContact", respuesta);
            }
            else {
                console.log("Failed with state: " + state);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Apex:

```
public with sharing class contactEditApex {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static contact__c createContact(contact__c contact) {
        System.debug(contact);
        upsert contact;
        return contact;
    }
    @AuraEnabled
     public static List<contact__c> getcontact(Integer nombre) {
        System.debug(nombre);
        Integer targetDepartment = 36809455;
        return [SELECT first_name__c, last_name__c, document_number__c, height__c, gender__c, eyes_color__c, hair_color__c FROM contact__c WHERE document_number__c = :targetDepartment];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `{"valueToNumber": valueToNumber}` to your action,

But the parameter name it's expecting is `nombre`.

Also, while I haven't run into this in a while, I remember passing an integer to an action used to cause errors.

If you still have problems after changing the parameter name, try typecasting it to a string as you pass it and convert it later in the `Apex` method. ie:

```
{"nombre": nombre + ""} //will convert to string
```

And in the apex:

```
public static List<contact__c> getcontact(String nombre) {
  Integer realNombre = Integer.valueOf(nombre);
  ///etc
```